# why is there extra content embedded in a cell after importing a TSV file into R

Tags: r

just doing some analysis on some data. After importing the TSV file into R Studio, the data look pretty good when you view them but if you actually call a cell, there is extra content embedded in it.

For example, the file name is AIA.

In R, input: >AIA[1,20]

> [1] 15026000
>
> 3848 Levels: 0 10000 100000 1000000 10006000 10012000 10020000 10024000 10030000 10032000 1004000 ... NULL

But 15026000 is what I see in the file and the data I need. How can I get rid of the extra stuff? Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Regarding the linked question, the same applies to `read.table()`. [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information) will also be useful to you.

Comment: Please, show the piece of code you are using to read the TSV file. I guess there is *no* parameter `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.